# Using Virtual Box with Ubuntu 64-bit, can't get Cordova to add android platform to project

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova, ant

Good Morning,

I am having difficulty adding a platform to a Cordova project that is created via the CLI.

What I have done:

I have installed Ubuntu 64-bit 12.04 LTS in a Virtual Box.
I removed the included java and added jdk-7
I added the sdk for Android and when I type "android" in the terminal I get the Android SDK Manager, I have run all updates and install all tools.
I have installed Eclipse as an IDE

When I create the project, it creates just fine, but when I try to add a platform, it won't add the platform, but it gives no errors either.  I have checked the owner/group of the created files and they are mine, but I have also tried "sudo cordova platform add android" and it gives the same result.  Here is a paste of my terminal window:

/-------------------- Start of Terminal Paste ------------------/

jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev$ cordova create seTest com.seTest "SE Test"

Creating a new cordova project with name "SE Test" and id "com.seTest" at location "/home/jcmacon/WebDev/seTest"

jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev$ cd seTest

jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev/seTest$ cordova platform add android

Creating android project...

jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev/seTest$ cordova platforms ls

Installed platforms:

Available platforms: android, blackberry10, firefoxos, ubuntu

jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev/seTest$ cd platforms/

jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev/seTest/platforms$ ls

jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev/seTest/platforms$ ls -l

total 0

jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev/seTest/platforms$ cordova -v

3.4.0-0.1.3

jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev/seTest/platforms$ ant -version

Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011

jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev/seTest/platforms$ cd ..

jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev/seTest$ ls -l

total 24

-rw-rw-r-- 1 jcmacon jcmacon  488 Mar 15 08:50 config.xml

drwxrwxr-x 2 jcmacon jcmacon 4096 Mar 15 08:50 hooks

drwxrwxr-x 2 jcmacon jcmacon 4096 Mar 15 08:50 merges

drwxrwxr-x 2 jcmacon jcmacon 4096 Mar 15 08:50 platforms

drwxrwxr-x 2 jcmacon jcmacon 4096 Mar 15 08:50 plugins

drwxrwxr-x 5 jcmacon jcmacon 4096 Mar 15 08:50 www

/---------   End of Terminal Paste ---------------------/

Please help me figure out what the issue is.  I have scoured Google and tried every solution I could find.  This is the 3rd attempt to get it working within Virtual Box.  Nothing has worked.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what error you got my friend?

Comment: That is the problem, there is no error, it just doesn't add the platform.

Comment: I didn't saw any error here. please clarify

Comment: When I use the command "cordova platform add android" I get the message "Creating android project..." then it goes back to the prompt without copying any files.  When I look in the platforms folder of my project there is no android folder, and when I run the command "cordova platforms ls" I get the response "Installed platforms: then a line break and Available platforms: android, blackberry10, firefoxos, ubuntu"

Comment: Run the command again with debug on "cordova platform add android -d" this will give you more info

Comment: I ran the command and here is the result.  jcmacon@jcmacon-VirtualBox:~/WebDev/seTest2$ cordova platform add android -d
cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
Creating android project...
Running command: /home/jcmacon/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create args=["--cli","/home/jcmacon/WebDev/seTest2/platforms/android","com.example.seTest2","SE Test2"]
It did not add the platform.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it helps, but using Shared Folders (vboxsf) seems to create more problems than to solve them.

I ended up developing on the guest-filesytem and copying my binaries to my windows-host to be able to test.